# How can I get the Ip address of server from which response is coming?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I'm a newbie to JMeter currently, I'm testing a Rest API, I need to record the server IP from which the response is coming.

I'm able to test the API but not able to record the IP address.
How can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you send to server name in variable `serverName`, so add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) (or other JSR223 element) and get the IP using [InetAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html):

> This class represents an Internet Protocol (IP) address.

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(vars.get("serverName")); 
log.info address.getHostAddress();
vars.put("serverIP", address.getHostAddress());
```

You can then use `${serverIP}` variable

Comment: How to copy IP after script? I'm using url directly.

Comment: you have variable available after script, just use `${serverIP}`

Comment: I'm getting  java.net.UnknownHostException while running it.

Comment: So you can't . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911590/inetaddress-getbyname-fails-behind-proxy

Comment: Indeed, I'm able to get IP of others but not for my url.Thank you very much for support it helps alot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   log.info('Source IP address: ' + InetAddress.getByName(sampler.getDomain()).getHostAddress())
   ```

   It will print the IP address to *jmeter.log* file

   [image: JMeter Get Source IP address]
3. If you want to save this IP for later re-use you can amend the code like:

   ```
   vars.put('ip', InetAddress.getByName(sampler.getDomain()).getHostAddress())
   ```

   and add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=ip
   ```

   As a result you will have an extra column in .jtl file containing IP address of the server.

More information:

- [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: hi, I'm getting following exception : ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.net.UnknownHostException

Comment: Thank you very much for support it helps alot.It's getting blocked.